# Custom filter and Rest framework not working simultaneously

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement the Django filter in my views class. But the problem is when I am using the `filter_class` then `filter_fields` & 'search_fields' is not working and vice versa.

My views.py code is :

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter, SearchFilter

class CustomLoggerAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = serializers.CustomLoggerSerializer
    filter_class = filters.LogsFilter
    queryset = models.CustomLogger.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter,)
    pagination_class = pagination.PostLimitOffsetPagination
    filter_fields = ('user','user_sensor','sensor_type',)
    search_fields = ('message')
```

and my filters.py class:

```
class LogsFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    start_date = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='created_at', lookup_expr='gte')
    end_date = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='created_at', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomLogger
        fields = ('start_date', 'end_date')
```

I want both filters. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is right, if you specify a `filterser_class`, then the `filter_fields` in the view are ignored. The solution is easy, just put those `filter_fields` in the `fields` of your `LogsFilter` Meta class:

```
class LogsFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    start_date = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='created_at', lookup_expr='gte')
    end_date = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='created_at', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomLogger
        fields = ('start_date', 'end_date', 'user','user_sensor','sensor_type')
```